# Improving host resolve speeds with shared internet connection (wifi-ethernet)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, lag, timeout

I recently set up my workstation at home to work remotely. I don't have a wi-fi device for it, so I am currently accessing the internet from my desktop by a [shared connection](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) with my laptop, like this:

ROUTER   <--{wifi}-->   LAPTOP   <--{ethernet}-->   DESKTOP

Both machines are running Linux Mint.

This works well enough, but it seems to add enough of a lag in connection that I have these recurring issues:

1. quite often, webpages will fail to load on the first attempt from my desktop. When this happens, Firefox gives the "Unable to connect" message. (Refreshing the page 2 or 3 times generally fixes this, so it's annoying, but not a big deal).
2. At the command line, when trying to access a remote resource, I sometimes get some variant of "couldn't resolve host". When this happens, I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

I cannot replicate #2 above right now, but I hope this description is enough to go on.

I think this must be a latency or lag issue - i.e. there is some maximum response time "MRT" (I don't know the technical name) within which my machine expects a response from a remote server, and if no response arrives within MRT, I get a timeout or "cannot resolve remote host" error. I would like to increase MRT, assuming that can be done with some configurable setting on my desktop machine. Is this possible?

Comment: "I know this must be a latency or lag issue" - How do you know? It might be other things, e.g. non working IPv6, but working IPv4 over the "shared connection". Have you tried **debugging** it (e.g. with Wireshark)?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the reply. I guess I don't. Changed "know" to "think." All I know is there are connection problems on the desktop that aren't on the laptop. I will look into Wireshark and report back.